# SQL API for *NIX C++

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, sqlapi++

I am currently writing a client-server app for the iOS platform. The client is written in Obj-C, and the server uses C++ on OSX11.9. Since I intend to run the server software on an Ubuntu dedicated server, I am trying my best to keep the serverside code portable.

To store data about users and user-game-relations I intend to use an SQL database (most likely MySQL or possibly PostgreSQL since I'm familiar with those). I know that it is possible to read from/write to the database through a filedescriptor just like I do in my TCP module, but I wish to utilize a higher-level SQL communications API to make the programming process quicker.

Can anyone recommend me a good open source/free SQL API for *NIX C++? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here:

1. Use native database SDK. They are usually distributed along with the database installation or as separate downloads/packets. The upside is you can get maximum speed out of it. Downside is that you'll be limited by your initial choice - no switching afterwards without rewriting part of application.
2. Use a C++ ORM (example: [ODB](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/)). This gives you DB independence along with some tasty features, at the cost of slightly reduced speed.

Answer (score 1):

[unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org) supports both MySQL and PostgreSQL. Take a look at it.